# parser error when trying to make nested structure for creating a new user

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

```
contract PersonalInfo{
    
    enum gender {MALE, FEMALE}
    
    struct Pdetails {
    
        string fName;
        string lName;
        int256 age;
        gender Gender;
    }
    
    struct Addr{
    
        string line1;
        string line2;
        string city;
        string state;
        int256 pincode;
    }
  
    struct UserInfo{
        
        Addr addr;
        Pdetails pdetails;
    }

    mapping(address => uint)  UserInfo;

    function createUser(address _userAddress, uint256 _userId, string _fName, string _lName, int256 _age, enum _gender, string _line1, string _line2, string _city, string _state, int256 _pincode  ) public { <------getting error here
    User storage UserInfo = users[_userAddress];
    require(!user.set);
  //Store the user
    users[_userAddress] = User(
        {
        id: _userId,
        first_name: _fName,
        last_name: _lName,
        age: _age,
        gender : _gender,
        Addr line1: _line1,
        Addr line2: _line2,
        city: _city,
        state: _state,
        pincode: _pincode
        
        set: true
    }
    );
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

The error is how the enum is passed as parameter. This is incorrect:

```
enum _gender
```

It has to be declared as

```
gender _gender
```

The contract should look like

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract PersonalInfo {
    
    enum gender {MALE, FEMALE}
    
    struct Pdetails {
    
        string fName;
        string lName;
        int256 age;
        gender Gender;
    }
    
    struct Addr{
    
        string line1;
        string line2;
        string city;
        string state;
        int256 pincode;
    }
  
    struct UserInfo{
        
        Addr addr;
        Pdetails pdetails;
        bool set;
    }

    mapping(address => UserInfo)  users;

    function createUser(address _userAddress, uint256 _userId, string memory _fName, string memory _lName, int256 _age, gender _gender, string memory _line1, string memory _line2, string memory _city, string memory _state, int256 _pincode  ) public { // <------getting error here
        UserInfo storage user = users[_userAddress];
        require(!user.set);
        //Store the user
        users[_userAddress] = UserInfo({
            pdetails: Pdetails({
                fName: _fName,
                lName: _lName,
                age: _age,
                Gender: _gender}),
            addr: Addr({
                line1: _line1,
                line2: _line2,
                city: _city,
                state: _state,
                pincode: _pincode}),
            set: true
        });
    }
}
```